# Validate with RegExp

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a string through a regular expression.
The validation is :
Every characters are valid but the string can not contain only the hyphen character or just white spaces.
For example

```
'-' -> NOT OK
' ' -> NOT OK
'--' -> OK
'-prwe'-> OK
'p u' -> OK
```

I am trying this regexp : `[^([^-]|[^\s])]`
But it gives me an error saying "Unbalanced parenthesis"
If I just use `^([^-]|[^\s])` the regexp is valid but this way I am not negating the capturing group, in this case the `^` sign means "Start of string".
My idea in pseudo regexp is this -> `NOT((NOT '-')|(NOT '\s'))`

Comment: `[]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), not group. `[^..]` is negation of character class. Also you can't use groups inside character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aliteralmind's answer is great for checking to see if they screwed up. If you want to do additional parsing in the same step, you'll need negative lookahead, e.g. `^(?!(?:-|\s*)$).*`.

Answer (score 2):

Check for this, and tell the user they messed up if it matches:

```
^(-| +)$
```

Or you can just check the *trimmed* string, if it equals a single dash:

```
if(input.trim().equals("-"))  {
   throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot be a single dash or only spaces");
}
```

Comment: But how can i negate the above regular expression "^(-| +)$" ?

Comment: Negate it with the if: `if(Pattern.compile("^(-| +)$").matcher(input).matches()) {  throw error...`

Comment: @tt0686 can we see how you are using this regex? In case you want to use it with `matches` just use it as `if (!yourString.matches(regex))` (notice `!` before `matches`).

Comment: @tt0686 I "negated" it in my answer with negative lookahead.

Comment: @tto686: Honestly, I'd recommend using the non-regex check. It's clearer and more concise.

Comment: Am asking how can i negate it through regular expression syntax not through another language, please

Comment: @Pshemo sometimes, usually with config files, negating in-code isn't a clean option, and you want to negate the pattern, itself.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann That is one of reasons I asked how this regex is used.

Comment: Your question tagged Java. So how is Java "another language"? Why do you *have* to negate this in regex, if you're using it in the context of Java? Negating this regex is moderately complicated, so why *not* use Java?

Comment: It sure stinks having your answer accepted and then unaccepted.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann I get your reasoning for negation. If that's true, it would have been useful to have this information in the OP's question.

Comment: Sorry for the unaccepted answer but i have to accept the answer that fix the problem,probably i was not totally clear when asking the question but in the start of the question i explicitly wrote "I want to validate a string through a regular expression.".
Anyway i am very thankfully by all the answers and your availability.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways you can do this.

1) `.{2,}` : any characters more than once

2) `^[\-\s]$` : it means space or hyphen. So check for not(`!`) in if condition.

3) if `string.equals("-")` or `string.equals(" ")`. Only if these two characters in consideration!

4) can't think of it, but lot mores available!